# Vaadin Plugin in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, vaadin

In [Vaadin's website](https://vaadin.com/learn#development) it says that only Eclipse and NetBeans have fully functional (which sets up project, compiles your widgets, provides a visual editor for drag&drop) Vaadin plugin.

I wonder whether IntelliJ has any plugin or support for Vaadin, if not why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays there is a Vaadin plugin for IntelliJ: [Vaadin support](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=6727). However, haven't tried it myself because I use Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that plug in. Yet, it's not a official plugin released by IntelliJ team and if you check the comments you will notice that it has lots of bugs..

Comment: As far as I know (and I work for Vaadin), that's the only Vaadin plugin for IntelliJ. A blog post about the plugin was released today at [vaadin.com](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/intellij-idea-is-now-even-better).

Comment: @HenriKerola Can you post an update on the proper way to use Vaadin 7 with IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.1? Should we be installing a Maven Archetype without any need for a Vaadin plugin or built-in Vaadin support?